# Issue using position dodge vertically in ggplots with geom_linerange in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm relatively new to R, and I am having issues with avoiding overlapping line ranges using geom_linerange and position_dodge with ggplot. I am comparing 2 different sets of age ranges for each individual in the study data. I would like to show the two ranges side-by-side, rather than display on the same ID line. Here is the data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", 
"V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), Age_Range1_Start = c(39L, 21L, 28L, 
35L, 35L, 20L, 21L, 28L, 20L, 29L, 28L, 20L, 49L, 20L, 39L, 21L, 
39L, 21L, 20L, 28L, 30L, 29L, 21L, 28L, 29L, 35L), Age_Range1_End = c(69L, 
42L, 52L, 57L, 57L, 43L, 42L, 52L, 43L, 44L, 52L, 43L, 65L, 43L, 
69L, 42L, 69L, 42L, 43L, 52L, 54L, 44L, 42L, 52L, 44L, 57L), 
    Age_Range2_Start = c(46L, 43L, 49L, 46L, 48L, 34L, 37L, 45L, 
    44L, 46L, 37L, 43L, 51L, 45L, 48L, 36L, 53L, 44L, 24L, 43L, 
    45L, 49L, 34L, 45L, 22L, 30L), Age_Range2_End = c(87L, 80L, 
    92L, 86L, 90L, 64L, 69L, 83L, 81L, 85L, 68L, 80L, 97L, 84L, 
    89L, 68L, 100L, 83L, 45L, 82L, 83L, 92L, 64L, 84L, 42L, 56L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))
>
```

Here is the R code I used

```
ggplot(data) + theme_minimal() + coord_flip() + 
geom_linerange(aes(x=ID, ymin=Age_Range1_Start, ymax=Age_Range1_End, color="Method 1", size=1.5)) +
geom_linerange(aes(x=ID, ymin=Age_Range2_Start, ymax=Age_Range2_End, color="Method 2", size=1.5), position=position_dodge(width=1)) +
labs(x="ID", y="Age Range", title="Method Age Range Comparison")
```

It produces the following plot:
[image]

Is it possible to shift (or dodge) the line ranges for Method 2 such that they appear slightly below or inferior to the age ranges for Method 1? I do not understand why the position_dodge code does not shift the values.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO could you please use `dput()` to share your `data` variable with us? This makes it easier to reconstruct your data and try your code.

Comment: Ah, thank you for letting me know about using dput()! I have edited the post to reflect this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you organize your data in another format you can do the trick, as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

data = data.frame(
  ID = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'), 2),
  Start = c(39, 21, 28, 35, 35, 20, 21, 28, 46, 43, 49, 46, 48, 34, 37, 45),
  End = c(69, 42, 52, 57, 57, 43, 42, 52, 87, 80, 92, 86, 90, 64, 69, 83),
  Method = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 8))
)
data$Method = as.factor(data$Method)

ggplot(data) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_linerange(aes(x = ID, ymin = Start, ymax = End, colour = Method),
                 size = 1.5, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = 'ID', y = 'Age Range', title = 'Method Age Range Comparison')
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Note that I gather the starts together and the ends together. Then, I labeled each of them as method 1 or 2.

Also remember using `position_dodge2()` when you flip the coordinates.